# tbl_svysummary no longer working for factor variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I recently updated gtsummary to 1.7.1 and find `tbl_svysummary` is no longer working for my factor variables. For example I'm trying to create a table with two variables that are labeled factors (RE_US, PAPYNOEV3YR) using this code:

```
PAPTABLE = why_subd %>%
    tbl_svysummary(by = RE_US, include = PAPYNOEV3YR, statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{p}%")
```

and am getting this error

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `df_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `left_join()`:
! Can't join `x$by` with `y$by` due to incompatible types.
ℹ `x$by` is a <character>.
ℹ `y$by` is a <labelled>.
Backtrace:
  1. why_subd %>% ...
 18. dplyr:::left_join.data.frame(., svy_p, by = c("by", "variable_levels"))
```

I tried converting these variables to characters which works but prefer to keep them as labeled factors, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post an example we can run on our machines, aka a minimal reprex https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ ? It looks like you have a variable of class `labelled`, which is not a typical R class. Could be related to your problem....

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg That ended up being the problem, I had to convert them to 'factor'. Thanks for your help! Your package is awesome.